# "This app isn't compatible with your phone" Android 7.0

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've got a basic web app that is a splash page activity followed by a web view action. I am trying to install it on my samsung s7 phone. We built the application using Visual Studio 2014 with Xamarin and am able to build and deploy a package. 
We tested the application using Genymotion samsung s7 emulator and it works there. When trying to load the application to the actual phone, the error I receive is "App not installed. This app isn't compatible with your phone". 
I need help in two ways. How do I get the error logs to figure out what my actual problem is or is there a place where I verify my settings to ensure that its compatible with my phone?

Here is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 android:versionCode="1" 
 android:versionName="1.0" 
 package="Application.Webview" 
 android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application 
         android:label="HomeDown" 
         android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
     </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is a log file that I found

```
 08-18 19:26:58.364: D/InputReader(1578): Input event(6): value=0 
 when=12676335778000
 08-18 19:26:58.364: D/InputReader(1578): Input event(6): value=0 
 when=12676335778000
 08-18 19:26:58.364: I/InputReader(1578): Touch event's action is 0x1 
 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, s=] when=12676335778000
 08-18 19:26:58.365: I/InputDispatcher(1578): Delivering touch to 
 (26207): action: 0x1, toolType: 1
 08-18 19:26:58.365: D/ViewRootImpl@eece518InstallAppProgress: 
 ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
 08-18 19:26:58.365: I/InstallAppProgress(26207): Finished installing 
 HomeDown.HomeDown
 08-18 19:26:58.367: W/MultiScreenManagerService(1578): 
 moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): The task has more than one activity
 08-18 19:26:58.368: D/ActivityManager(1578): moveToFront() : 
 reason=finishActivity adjustFocus setFocusedActivity isAttached=true
 TaskRecord{e3392e7d0 #15169 A=com.sec.android.app.myfiles U=0 
 StackId=1 sz=2}
 08-18 19:26:58.372: D/InputDispatcher(1578): Focused application set 
 to: xxxx
 08-18 19:26:58.373: D/ActivityTrigger(1578): ActivityTrigger
 activityPauseTrigger
 08-18 19:26:58.373: D/GameManagerService(1578): sem_perfomance_mode: 0
08-18 19:26:58.380: D/ActivityManager(1578): 
resumeTopActivityInnerLocked() : #1 prevTask=TaskRecord{e3392e7d0 #15169
A=com.sec.android.app.myfiles U=0 StackId=1 sz=2} 
next=ActivityRecord{168f10bd0 u0 
com.sec.android.app.myfiles/.common.MainActivity
t15169} mFocusedStack=ActivityStack{4015b39d0 stackId=1, 2 tasks}
```

Comment: Can you share your Module:app gradle code?

Comment: Do you have jniLibs in your project?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am *assuming* your APK was *not* built with the correct ABIs

Your Samsung S7 has either a Snapdragon 820 (`ABI = ARMv8-A` **or** a Exynos 8890 (`ABI` = `ARMv7`) SoC depending upon where in the world you bought it.

Thus you need your APK built with `ARMABI-V7A` at a minimum in order to run on all the Samsung S7s in the world, the GenyMotion emulator would be using an `x86` ABI.

The easiest fix is to able all the ABIs to be packaged into your APK, under the Xamarin Android "Advanced" build setting you will find the ABI options there (They can be different for debug and release builds, so change them in both configuration if needed...)

[image]